# Kubernetes RBAC ClusterRole

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount

I'm trying to deploy some deployments out of my gitlab runner.
I do not see the error in my clusterrole and in the rolebindng.

Here the error I get:

```
from server for: "./deployment.yaml": deployments.apps "demo-deployment" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-runner:gitlab-ci" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "gitlab-runner"
```

Here the role I create:

```
kubectl create clusterrole deployment-test --verb=\* --resource=deployments

kubectl create clusterrolebinding deployment-test-binding --clusterrole=deployment-test --serviceaccount=gitlab-runner:gitlab-ci
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please check if namespace :  gitlab-runner and service account: gitlab-ci are present on the cluster ?

Comment: Yes, they are present